# How to handle HTTP error codes (404) on the frontend-side in Nuxt 3?

Tags: nuxtjs3

In Nuxt 2, a `layouts/error.vue` component is used. I tried with Nuxt 3 but it didn't work out.

I can not find it in the documentation (https://v3.nuxtjs.org/guide/directory-structure/pages, https://v3.nuxtjs.org/guide/directory-structure/layouts)

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### SPA

Writing an `error.vue`-file inside the root-folder works and the error object can be passed as prop to this component. The object as the following type:

```js
error: { 
  url: string; 
  statusCode: string; 
  statusMessage: string; 
  message: string; 
  description: string; 
  data: any; 
}
```

#### Multiple pages

Create a `404.vue`-file inside the root-folder

Comment: Please edit you comment to be the accepted answer. Writing an `error.vue`inside the root-folder works and the error object can be passed as prop to this component. The object as the following type: error: {
    url: string;
    statusCode: string;
    statusMessage: string;
    message: string;
    description: string;
    data: any;
  }

Comment: I edit the answer to keep the solution part only. If the modification is accepted, I will accept this as answer and upvote.

Comment: @wittgenstein What if I don't want the page to use the error page layout, but still return the 404 status code?

Comment: @iusting - how about using a `navigateTo()` with 404 status as params? Of course you have to create this redirect on a specific level using `[id].vue`. It depends on your code structure, but this would be my first approach.

Comment: @wittgenstein Thanks for the reply. I ended up using `setResponseStatus` instead and it worked like a charm:
`const event = useRequestEvent();`

`setResponseStatus(event, 404);`

doc link: https://nuxt.com/docs/api/utils/set-response-status